# How can I determine the position of a contentcontol in a Word Document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js

We're developing an Office.js application for creating documents. We want to integrate with a digital signing solution. This solution requires a position (x and y) for the signature in Pixels. But because the content of the document will vary, the position of the signature is not fixed. We use contentcontrols for our other dynamic content, so I'm trying to find a way of reading or calculating the position of a specific contentcontrol.

If there are any other elements we can use to determine the position that would be fine too. I would prefer a Office.JS solution, but OpenXML would also work.

In documentation there seems no support for getting the position. For Ranges there is this compareLocationWith() method, so you can get the position relative to another range, but no coordinates.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions!
Thank you.

Comment: FWIW this is not even a "simple" task in the much more extensive COM object model. Word is a word processor, not a layout program, so the location on the page is (as far as Word's internal logic is concerned) not really relevant. Word "flows" content onto the page, according to its formatting and how the currently selected printer will interpret it, but it doesn't "care" about pixel locations. In the COM world there's a Windows API call that's been partially implented in the object model: `GetPoint`. This sort of works, but isn't 100% reliable. Not that this really helps you...

Comment: Thank you Cindy. I've reached out to the developers of the Sign-solution. Hope they have an other solution. And otherwise I'll be diving into the COM solution.

Comment: I expect we here at Native Documents would be able to expose this info for you in our Word file viewer/editor.